Cannot access Sony VAIO BIOS to install Ubuntu
I have been taking in old Windows laptops and putting Ubuntu on them, giving them out free via various care sectors. Usually I have no problem getting into the BIOS to enable boot from a usb. However, I have been given an old Sony VAIO which is locked to boot Windows 7. All the usual F keys do nothing - the thing still boots Windows. There was one user and I do not have the password, so I just get to the login screen. The “Assist” button gets to VAIO Care Rescue and there are no useful options there. Any ideas which might help? Thanks.

Watch the screen as you power up. Most BIOSes print a hint on the screen for a shory time.

@JeffreyR 'In a state in which the power is off, press the power button while holding down the [F3] or [F4] button. VJZ12A * Series, + side or the VOL (volume control) button – Press and hold the side, press the power button.' Hope this helps. Note: Not really on topic.

Thanks, I've tried this and various combinations of power button & F's. Still no joy.
